# How to get MySQL rows filtered by one column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL table called cabeceraticket.

It has the fields: id, sesion, nummesa, numplano, estado,sesion...

```
id=44, nummesa= 21, numplano = 7, estado = 100
id=45, nummesa= 22, numplano = 7, estado = 100
id=46, nummesa= 24, numplano = 7, estado = 400
id=47, nummesa= 24, numplano = 7, estado = 100
id=48, nummesa= 7,  numplano = 7, estado = 100
```

I need to list all rows filtering for field nummesa. I only need the latest row for same nummesa values.

In this case the query result should list the rows with id= 44,45,47,48

The row with id=46 should not be listed, then it has for nummesa the same value as row with id=47, but its id is greater.

This is the base query:

```
SELECT nummesa,numplano,estado,id 
FROM cabeceraticket  
WHERE sesion = 8 
AND numplano = 7 
GROUP BY nummesa
```

The given values for session and estado are coming from variables, I have put here specific values for simplicity.

Comment: Do you want specifically 47 or you don't care if its 47 or 46?

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz, I need to get always the latest row for a certain nummesa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to just join your table to a subquery which finds the latest `id` value for each `nummesa`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.nummesa, t1.numplano, t1.estado
FROM cabeceraticket t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT numessa, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM cabeceraticket
    GROUP BY numessa
) t2
    ON t1.numessa = t2.numessa AND t1.id = t2.max_id;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you can take advantage of `ROW_NUMBER`, for a slightly less verbose query:

```
SELECT id, nummesa, numplano, estado
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY numessa ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM cabeceraticket
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: If I use GROUP BY nummesa, will I always get the latest row for the same nummesa value?

Comment: The MAX(id) give you the latest row.
If you just do a group by ( without join or max ), it could give you the latest, but it also could give you something else. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT nummesa, numplano, estado, id
FROM cabeceraticket
WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM cabeceraticket WHERE sesion = 8 AND numplano = 7
              GROUP BY nummesa )
```

Comment: What is `sesion`?

Comment: It is in the base query, see in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself and selecting just the latest row (and you are avoiding the subquery)

```
SELECT t1.* FROM cabeceraticket t1
LEFT JOIN cabeceraticket t2
ON t1.nummesa = t2.nummesa AND t1.id < t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```